# sqlite columns not getting created

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to add something to my database but I keep getting an error saying that a column does not exist. I looked at the table using `root explorer` and it only creates the first 2 columns which would be `id` and `name`. That is all I had in there at first but then I added a few columns and now it gives me the error even after I did a fresh install of the program.

Its a content provider if that matters any

```
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282): Error inserting series=0 team_pos=0 handed=0 name=Allen, Andrew substitute=0 game=0 team=0 average=0
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table bowlers_table has no column named series: , while compiling: INSERT INTO bowlers_table(series,team_pos,handed,name,substitute,game,team,average) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:146)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:367)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:253)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:111)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1737)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at com.tyczj.bowling.BowlersDB.insert(BowlersDB.java:102)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:203)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:721)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at com.tyczj.bowling.Bowlers.onDoneClick(Bowlers.java:58)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2690)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3122)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12020)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/SQLiteDatabase(23282):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2695)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3122)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12020)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2690)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    ... 11 more
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282): Caused by: android.database.SQLException: Failed to insert row into content://com.tyczj.bowling.bowlersdb/bowlers_table
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at com.tyczj.bowling.BowlersDB.insert(BowlersDB.java:108)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:203)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:721)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    at      com.tyczj.bowling.Bowlers.onDoneClick(Bowlers.java:58)
12-08 16:55:21.470: E/AndroidRuntime(23282):    ... 14 more
```

here is when I insert

```
public void onDoneClick(View v){
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(BowlersDB.NAME,et.getText().toString());
    contentValues.put(BowlersDB.HANDED,"0");
    contentValues.put(BowlersDB.TEAM,"0");
    contentValues.put(BowlersDB.SUB,"0");
    contentValues.put(BowlersDB.POSITION,"0");
    contentValues.put(BowlersDB.AVERAGE,"0");
    contentValues.put(BowlersDB.GAME,"0");
    contentValues.put(BowlersDB.SERIES,"0");
    et.setText("");
    getContentResolver().insert(BowlersDB.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

}
```

and my database insert

```
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long rowID = db.insert(BOWLERS_TABLE,null, values);
    if(rowID > 0){
        Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE,rowID);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri,null);
        return _uri;
    }else{
        throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
    }
}
```

and how I create the table in the content provider

```
private void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + BOWLERS_TABLE + "(" + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                NAME + " TEXT " + TEAM + " TEXT " + SUB + " TEXT " + POSITION + " TEXT " + AVERAGE + " TEXT " + GAME + " TEXT " +
                 SERIES + " TEXT " + HANDED + " TEXT);");
    }
```

I have done a bunch of tables before this way so I dont know why this is not creating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the comma after your " TEXT "s, in the SQL code that creates the database table.

Comment: Well, you forgot the comma after all of them (except the last one, which doesn't require a comma)

Comment: @tyczj all of them except the closing one should be `" TEXT, "`.  Try to meet the answer half-way